# Solidworks PDM API - IEdmBomView.GetRows does not return the same items for the BOM that are in PDM

Tags: c#, api, solidworks

I have a routine in C# to export the BOM from Solidworks, but when I verified, the 2 items marked in the image are not returned by "GetRows" routine of the "IEdmBomView" class. The items are normal in Solidworks. And when I export the BOM to Excel by PDM, the 2 items are exported normally. Any idea?

[image: BOM View]

Comment: I think it has to do with how you are getting the IEdmBomView object.  What are you using to get that?  If you could post your code you used that would help.

Comment: You should ask this here https://forum.solidworks.com/community/api